Visual Studio 2022 not showing unit tests by group
I am new to unit testing and have set a bunch up.  I wanted to be able to group them so I can run tests based on group if necessary.  I have set up a few of my test methods like this based on a Microsoft article:
 [TestMethod, TestCategory("ReCaptcha")]
 public async Task TestValidateGoogleReCaptcha_NullResponse(){
   // some code here
}

I have done this on 3 test methods and selected the group by "traits" in the group by drop down.  The others I have no TestCategory.  It says all of my test have no traits

I cannot figure out what I am missing.  Does anyone have the same issue and a possible fix?
Thank you

So after spending lots of wasted time on this, I found an answer, well, sort of, but it works.  What I did was upgraded VS to the most recent version at this time: 17.12.3.
After I re-opened VS, it still was not showing correctly.  So, I kind of just gave up and continued writing my other test cases.  Once I clicked on Run All, and it finished, the display refreshed and is now showing the grouping.  The funny thing is it does not show anything in the "traits" column, but at lest the grouping is now working.  I hope this helps someone else :

